# Unable to catch Exception using code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller code which save data in table but when I put more than max length column data , it is not retuning me STATUS false; nothing is happening. please help

```
function saveImproveUs(){   

        $status =array("STATUS"=>"false");

        try{
            $improveUs = array(
                'NAME' => trim($this->input->post('name')),
                'EMAIL' => trim($this->input->post('email')),
                'LOCATION' =>  trim($this->input->post('location')),
                'MESSAGE_TYPE' => trim($this->input->post('messageType')),
                'COMMENTS' => trim($this->input->post('comments'))
            );
            // Save improve us 
            $this->db->insert('trn_improve_us', $improveUs);

            if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
                $status = array("STATUS"=>"true");
            }

        }catch(Exception $ex)        {
            //show_error($ex);
            echo "I am in exception";
            exit;
        }
        echo json_encode (array($status)) ; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to throw the exception, it won't do this for you.

```
if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
    $status = array("STATUS"=>"true");
}
else {
    throw new Exception("Could not insert data");
}
```

Also inserting more data than a column can hold will automatically get cut-off in MySQL, the insert won't actually fail. You should use `strlen` to check the length of a string and validate it manually.

Comment: As you said mysql can not give a error see this details A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1406

Data too long for column 'COMMENTS' at row 1

INSERT INTO `trn_improve_us` (`NAME`, `EMAIL`, `LOCATION`, `MESSAGE_TYPE`, `COMMENTS`) VALUES ('sdfsdf', 'sdf@gmail.com', '23423', '1', 'dsflkl;fkl;sdkfl\ndsflkl;fkl;sdkfl\ndsflkl;fkl;sdkfl\ndsflkl;fkl;sdkfl\ndsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;sdkfldsflkl;fkl;